# ScyllaDB: Materialized View not updating

Tags: cql, scylla

This might be related to this issue: [ScyllaDB 2.1 - Inconsistency with Materialized View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51095309/scylladb-2-1-inconsistency-with-materialized-view)

But that was 2 years ago, I would have expected this to be fixed, as the docs say that MVs are updated based on the base table.

nodetool version reports ReleaseVersion: 3.0.8

My specific issue, given the table:

```
CREATE TABLE query (
    activity_id uuid,
    org_id text,
    subject_id uuid,
    result text,
    expires timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((org_id, activity_id), expires)
);
```

and the MV:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW janus.active_queries AS
    SELECT * FROM janus.query
    WHERE subject_id IS NOT NULL
        and org_id IS NOT NULL
        and activity_id IS NOT NULL
        and expires > toTimestamp(now())
    PRIMARY KEY ((org_id, subject_id), expires, activity_id);
```

The MV is never updated.  Dropping the MV and rebuilding it will give the the correct results for the base-table at the time of creation, but no updates to the MV occur.  I would expect records to fall out over time based on the relation "expires > toTimestamp(now())"

Am I mis-understanding how to use the MV? Do these kind of relations not work? Or is my version too old?

Comment: Or it occurs to me, that the now() may be being converted to a static timestamp value when the MV is created, and thus is never re-evaluated.  If this is the case, I could see limited uses for that, and it should really be called out in the docs, as I expect the now() to recalculate every time the query is evaluated like in regular cql.

Comment: Even if the evaluation time of `now()` would be delayed, as you suggested, will it help you? The check will still only be done during insertion - nothing will go back and remove existing rows as the `now()` time goes forward... So it sounds like delaying the `now()` evaluation won't really help you.